# How to calculate percent of downloading data from web service

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services

I call a method from web service to get a binary data. The data's size is more big. How to get the percent of downloading data from web service? I use BackgroundWorker thread to get data asynchorously.

Thanks.

**Update: This is the method from my web service**

```
[WebMethod]
        public byte[] Data()
        {
            byte[] buffer;
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("Services.rar");
            FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            try
            {
                int length = (int)fileStream.Length;  // get file length
                buffer = new byte[length];            // create buffer
                int count;                            // actual number of bytes read
                int sum = 0;                          // total number of bytes read

                // read until Read method returns 0 (end of the stream has been reached)
                while ((count = fileStream.Read(buffer, sum, length - sum)) > 0)
                    sum += count;  // sum is a buffer offset for next reading
            }
            finally
            {
                fileStream.Close();
            }
            return buffer;
        }
```

This method will return a binary file. And my codes to get data from this method in WinForm application:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            localhost.Service1 service = new localhost.Service1();
            byte[] data = service.Data();
// where I get data, time to finish getting data depended on file's size.
// I want to calculate the time to finish and display percentage
            }
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: You have left a lot of things for us to guess. Do you, by any chance, know the total size of the data to be downloaded and how much has been downloaded at any given instant ? ;)

Comment: only possible if the server sent a content-length response header or chunked encoding used.  Otherwise the client has no idea how much data to expect.

Comment: You take `less big / more big` to get the percent.

Comment: Sorry all, I add more details. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [soap extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480520.aspx) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This won't build but should give you the idea:
webResponse.ContentLength; will give total size assuming the server sends it.
Current progress can be kept track of. Use a delegate to update status in a ui thread.

```
    private delegate void UpdateProgessCallback(Int64 BytesRead, Int64 TotalBytes);

    private void Download(string url, string localPath)
    {
        using (WebClient wcDownload = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                // Create a request to the file we are downloading
                webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                // Set default authentication for retrieving the file
                webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
                // Retrieve the response from the server
                webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
                // Ask the server for the file size and store it
                Int64 fileSize = webResponse.ContentLength;

                // Open the URL for download 
                strResponse = wcDownload.OpenRead(txtUrl.Text);
                // Create a new file stream where we will be saving the data (local drive)
                strLocal = new FileStream(string localPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);

                // It will store the current number of bytes we retrieved from the server
                int bytesSize = 0;
                // A buffer for storing and writing the data retrieved from the server
                byte[] downBuffer = new byte[2048];

                // Loop through the buffer until the buffer is empty
                while ((bytesSize = strResponse.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    // Write the data from the buffer to the local hard drive
                    strLocal.Write(downBuffer, 0, bytesSize);
                    // Invoke the method that updates the form's label and progress bar
                    this.Invoke(new UpdateProgessCallback(this.UpdateProgress), new object[] { strLocal.Length, fileSize });
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                // When the above code has ended, close the streams
                strResponse.Close();
                strLocal.Close();
            }
        }

    private void UpdateProgress(Int64 BytesRead, Int64 TotalBytes)
    {
        // Calculate the download progress in percentages
        PercentProgress = Convert.ToInt32((BytesRead * 100) / TotalBytes);
        // Make progress on the progress bar
        prgDownload.Value = PercentProgress;
        // Display the current progress on the form
        lblProgress.Text = "Downloaded " + BytesRead + " out of " + TotalBytes + " (" + PercentProgress + "%)";

        if (BytesRead == TotalBytes)
        {
        //done
        }
    }
```